# jQuery hide() and show() on div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

jQuery hide() on button not working, followed then show() of div doesn't appear. Where it was went wrong?

But, it's working fine when internet is turned off. jQuery library was hosted locally.

```css
#loading {
    background: url('/img/loading.gif') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button id="submit" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
<div id="loading" style="display:none"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; // enable the button

  $('#submit').click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active"); // either $(this) or $('submit')
        $(this).hide(); // either $(this) or $('submit')
        $('#loading').show();
  });
});
```

Like said earlier, above code works fine when internet turned off. Also, tried the same with JS display:none and display:block, not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/945ovayj/1/

Comment: how  can you click `disabled` button?

Comment: Good catch @Satpal, i forgot to mention that. Before execute of above code it was enabled when user entered required items on input box. document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;

Comment: `disabled` property aside, this doesn't work because clicking the submit button causes the page to be unloaded as a new page is being requested. This means all UI updates stop.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Only if it is wrapped in `<form>` I guess...

Comment: Chances are, you aren't enabling the submit button at the right point. It works here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMxJeE

Comment: @Rayon true, although the point of a submit button is rather moot without one.

Comment: @D09r I edited the line which enables the button in to your question to save any confusion.

Comment: If it works fine with the internet turned off, you are probably loading another outside js script that has errors. What does your console return?

Comment: @dwreck08, I've bootstrap, jquery, and my code js all are called locally. On submit of this, calling function of XMLHttpRequest. Is that causing? Actually, I require button should disappear on click and show (loading gif file) until completion of XMLHttpRequest operation.

Comment: It's working without XMLHttpRequest calls, why not with it? any explanation and way to achieve with it. See this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563448/show-hide-html-element-on-javascript-xhr-request-function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you make a fiddle, the jQuery library is imported. Instead of giving the div a `display:none` you can use the `.hide()` function in jQuery when the `document` is `ready`. Here's the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/rr1gwyr7/2/